# Using Micromax 353G Dongle with Penta IS701C tablet

Tags: usb-host-mode, mobile-network

I have purchased Penta IS701C recently. I have a Micromax 353G dongle, and want to know if it supports my Penta tablet. If yes, how could I use the dongle in the Penta tab?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at [product specification](http://www.pantel.in/Products/T-Pad-IS701C.aspx) page of Penta IS701C, it appears that this dongle is not officially supported. But on same page it says that tablet does support 2G / 3G dongle so 
I see no reason why it should not work.